# icon grey custom UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I create a custom `UIActivityViewController` but when I load the icons that I do makes me see gray and you are pretty much loaded correctly, someone did it happen? how you have remedied?

```
ActivityViewCustomActivity *ca = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];
            ca.service = @"avanti";
            ca.image = image;
            ca.act = @"com.avanti.app";
            ActivityViewCustomActivity *fa = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];
            fa.service = @"facebook";
            fa.image = image;//[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-facebook.jpg"];
            fa.act = @"com.facebook.app";
            ActivityViewCustomActivity *tw = [[ActivityViewCustomActivity alloc]init];
            tw.service = @"twitter";
            tw.image = image;
            tw.act = @"com.twitter.app";
            UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
            [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                              applicationActivities:@[ca,fa,tw]];

            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];


            activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
            {
                if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"com.avanti.app"]) {

                NSLog(@" activityType: %@", activityType);
                NSLog(@" completed: %i", completed);

                NSString *name = [q objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                UIStoryboard *storyboar = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                ListViewController *list = [storyboar instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListViewController"];
                list.ide = ide;
                list.canale = name;

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:list animated:YES];
                }
                else if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.app"]){
                    NSLog(@" activityType: %@", activityType);
                    NSLog(@" completed: %i", completed);
                    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annulla" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Vuoi pubblicarlo ?" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
                    action.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

                    [self actionSheet:action clickedButtonAtIndex:2];

                    [action showInView:[self.view window]];
                }
                else if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"com.twitter.app"]){
                    NSLog(@" activityType: %@", activityType);
                    NSLog(@" completed: %i", completed);
                    [self shareTwitter];
                }
            };

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                NSLog(@"ipad");
            }
            else
            {
                [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }
```

e l'activity è così

```
- (NSString *)activityType
{
    return act;
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    return service;
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage
{

//    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 85.0f, 85.0f);
//    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
//    
//    rect = CGRectInset(rect, 15.0f, 15.0f);
//    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:10.0f];
//    [path stroke];
//    
//    rect = CGRectInset(rect, 0.0f, 10.0f);
//    [service drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:15.0f] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
//    
//    UIImage *imag = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//
//    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//    //UIImage *ima = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.jpg"];
//    return imag;

    UIImage *ima = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Facebook.png"];
    return ima;
//    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
//    {
//        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook_43x43"];
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        return image;
//    }
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    for (id obj in activityItems) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

}

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

- (void)performActivity
{
    // This is where you can do anything you want, and is the whole reason for creating a custom
    // UIActivity


    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}

+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory
{
    return UIActivityCategoryShare;
}
```

and the screenshot is here http://i57.tinypic.com/332vtjo.png

and .h is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ActivityViewCustomActivity : UIActivity 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *service;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *act;

- (NSString *)activityType;

- (NSString *)activityTitle;

- (UIImage *)activityImage;

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems;

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems;

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController;

- (void)performActivity;

+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory;

@end
```

Comment: Could your be clearer? Some code and/or some screenshots could be appreciated.?

Comment: code please and screenshot

Comment: I can not post the screenshot because I do not have enough reputation here, but the code is so

Comment: I am creating a custom controller activityview of activity but the icons remain gray for a reason? unfortunately do not have enough reputation can not answer with code or screenshots

Comment: when you launch your custom activityView everything is showed in gray, doesn't it?

Comment: writings are well written you can clearly see, only the icons are completely gray insert any image from url is that  for example UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed: @ "facebook.png"];

Comment: check if the dimension of your image fits into your activityIndicator

Comment: the size is right but I think the problem is that by default it takes another background or puts dull and the picture goes according to plan, or something else

Comment: please post UIActivityViewController.h , what the Type of image @property in it ?

Comment: ok try changing `property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;` to              `property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img;`   than set UIImage by:    `fa.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed=@"Icon_Facebook.png"];`

Comment: Now if I add these changes happening this http://i60.tinypic.com/2vk003l.png

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/10/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-text/)

Comment: the problem remains in any case also because the main part I took from here

Answer (score 1):

Try to add _ to your activityImage function 
Something like

```
- (UIImage *)_activityImage
{
return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Facebook.png"];
}
```